# Shell bash script does not run R

Tags: r, linux, bash, shell

I have an R script that I can run with

```
R CMD BATCH Rtest.R a.txt
```

and it successfully returns the results to a.txt. I am attempting to write a new shell script that plan to run daily, and have made the following script, called morning

```
#!/bin/bash
sh R CMD BATCH Rtest.R a.txt
cat a.txt >> predicted.txt
```

I run this with the following commands

```
chmod 755 morning
./morning
```

I can get this to work sort of, but end up with the error

```
sh: 0: Can't open R
```

and execution halts midway through. When I run it with a different command (such as echo alpha > a.txt) it works as expected.

I am working under Ubuntu 14.04

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `morning` file. Please also check if `R` is in the `PATH`.

```
#!/bin/bash

R CMD BATCH Rtest.R a.txt
cat a.txt >> predicted.txt
```

Comment: I can run R from anywhere in the directory. I think that is what you mean by checking if R is in the PATH @Ven Yao, but please correct me if I am wrong. I am new with writing shell scripts

Comment: And your shell script was wrong (extra `sh` at beginning, creating a new `PATH`) which @VenYao corrected.

Comment: I edited my morning file as suggested. Maybe I should learn more about PATH and writing shell scripts. Thanks to you both